# "overfull hbox (62.122123 too wide)" message in a long equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
2.\\
(a) Since there is only one observation the likelihood function only includes $p_1^{y_1}(1-p_1)^{(1-y_1)}$.\\\

=$>$ $L(\alpha  , \beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) =   p_1^{y_1}(1-p_1)^{(1-y_1)}$\\\

=$>$ $l(\alpha  , \beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) = ln(p_1^{y_1}(1-p_1)^{(1-y_1)})$\\\

=$>$ $l(\alpha  , \beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) = y_1ln(p_1) + (1 - y_1)ln(1 - p_1)$\\\

=$>$ $l(\alpha  , \beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) = y_1ln(\frac{1}{1-e^{-(\alpha + \beta_1 x_{11} + \beta_2 x_{12} + \beta x_{13})}}) + (1 - y_1)ln(1 - \frac{1}{1-e^{-(\alpha + \beta_1 x_{11} + \beta_2 x_{12} + \beta x_{13}}})$\\\
```

I got an error at the first line (as the app said). Is there a way to fix this? Thanks a lot guys

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. If I wrap your question in a simple `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, no errors occur. So the root cause is elsewhere.

Comment: That is, however, horrible mark up. Semantic mark up and a suitable multi-line maths environment would make things easier. `\begin{enumerate}... \end{enumerate}` and something from `amsmaths`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You have to introduce a line break in the fourth equation. However, that's not the only adjustment you should perform. I suggest you do the following:

- use `enumerate` environments; this will give you typographically sound amounts of indentation of the various items. Also, get rid of the manual line breaks.
- remove the instances of `=$>$`, as they are redundant. (Aside: if you really need it, do write it as `$\Rightarrow`.)
- place the four long equations in a single `align*` environment, and insert line breaks (with `\\` directives) after each of the first three equations as well as after the obvious point in the fourth equation
- don't over-use second-level subscripts and superscripts, especially not in the numerator or denominator of a fraction. Thus, instead of

  ```
  e^{-(\alpha + \beta_1 x_{11} + \beta_2 x_{12} + \beta x_{13})}
  ```

  do write

  ```
  \exp\bigl(-(\alpha + \beta_1 x_{11} + \beta_2 x_{12} + \beta x_{13})\bigr)
  ```

  Your readers will thank you.
- Increase the sizes of some of the parentheses using `\bigl(`, `\bigr)`, `\biggl(`, and `\biggr)` directives (see above for an example).
- Last but not least, please write `\ln` instead of just `ln`. That way, the letters "ln" will be typeset in the upright Roman typeface.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{1} % just for this example
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Since there is only 1 observation, the likelihood function only includes $p_1^{y_1}(1-p_1)^{(1-y_1)}$.
\begin{align*}
L(\alpha  , &\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) 
  = p_1^{y_1}(1-p_1)^{(1-y_1)}\\
l(\alpha  , &\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) 
  = \ln(p_1^{y_1}(1-p_1)^{(1-y_1)})\\
l(\alpha  , &\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) 
  = y_1\ln(p_1) + (1 - y_1)\ln(1 - p_1)\\
l(\alpha  , &\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3) 
  = y_1\ln\biggl(\frac{1}{1-\exp\bigl(-(\alpha + \beta_1 x_{11} + \beta_2 x_{12} + \beta x_{13})\bigr)}\biggr) \\
  &\quad+ (1 - y_1)\ln\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{1-\exp\bigl(-(\alpha + \beta_1 x_{11} + \beta_2 x_{12} + \beta x_{13})\bigr)}\biggr)
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```